# How to recalculate measure based on filtered values

Tags: mdx

I am a newbie in SSAS, I have encountered a minor issues in cube and I cant solve it in many days 
Please help me this, I very appreciate your ideas.

My cube has a measure that shows the percentage. 
The percentage does not displays correctly when we use filter.

#### For example:

```
*** Without filter any dimensions, it is correct
Age Percentage
15 - 24 11.64%
25 - 24 24.21%
35 - 44 24.03%
45 - 54 20.17%
55 - 64 12.92%
65+ 6.66%
Do not know 0.38%
Grand Total 100.00%

*** With filter Gender=Male (or any dimensions), it likes this. 
Age Percentage
15 - 24 4.72%
25 - 24 13.55%
35 - 44 15.87%
45 - 54 13.52%
55 - 64 8.07%
65+ 3.66%
Do not know 0.18%
Grand Total 59.58%
```

what I expect that it should be 100% in Grand Total and the percentage of each category must be recalculated.

Please help me !!!

Comment: Can you pls show how you add a filter? In SSRS? With MDX (pls show code then)..

Comment: @danie_aren: I'm sry. I cant, code is belong to my company (zzz). Sry, again . My company hire emp to solve this problems . Topic can close. Thanks for watching.